# Grouped/Nested List View

Tags: c#, ios, listview, xamarin, binding

I am developing an inventory manager Xamarin iOS application. I am trying to create a page where a user can add stocks, including a group of serial items to the store stocks. The design I need is a nested list view with multiple entries, where if the productId in the first list view belongs to a phone item, it will have an inner list view with entries for serialNumber values (the size of Stock.Quantity.) if a product is an accessory item, it will not have Serial Numbers.
I have tried grouping and nested ListViews but no avail.

**Stock Class:**

```
public class Stock
{

    [Key]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int StoreId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Store Store { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SerialNumber> SerialNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

**SerialNumber Class:**

```
 public class SerialNumber
{
    [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("StoreId")]
    public int StoreId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public string SerialNumberValue { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Stock Stock { get; set; }

}
```

**ViewModel Class:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Input;
using InventoryManager.Models;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace InventoryManager.ViewModels
{
public class AddStocksViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public AddStocksViewModel() {

        stocks = new ObservableCollection<Stock>();
        stocks.Add(new Stock() { StoreId = App.currentStore.StoreId, SerialNumbers = new ObservableCollection<SerialNumber>() });
        serialNumbers = new ObservableCollection<SerialNumber>();
        serialNumbers.Add(new SerialNumber());

    }
    public IList<Stock> stocks { get; set;  }
    public IList<SerialNumber> serialNumbers { get; set; }
    public IList<Stock> Stocks
    {
        get { return stocks; }
        set { stocks = value; }
    }


    public IList<SerialNumber> SerialNumbers {
        get { return serialNumbers; }
        set { serialNumbers = value; }

    }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public ICommand ProductIdChanged {
        get
        {
            return GetProduct;
        }  
    }

    public bool IsProductAPhone { get; set; } 
    //public Stock  Stock {get;set;}
    public Product Product { get; set; } 
    public ICommand GetProduct
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Product = await DataStore.GetProductAsync(ProductId);
                }
                catch
                {


                }
                finally
                {
                    if (Product != null)
                        IsProductAPhone = Product.ProductType == ProductType.Phone;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
}
```

**AddStocksPage Code behind**

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using InventoryManager.ViewModels;
    using Xamarin.Forms;
    using InventoryManager.Models;
namespace InventoryManager.Views
{
public partial class AddStocksPage : ContentPage
{
    AddStocksViewModel viewModel;

    public AddStocksPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel = new AddStocksViewModel();


    }
    public void OnProductIdChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        viewModel.GetProduct.Execute(null);
        //viewModel.Product.Id = (args.NewTextValue);
    }
    public void OnQuantityChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            int quantity = Int32.Parse((sender as Entry).Text);
            if (viewModel.IsProductAPhone)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++)
                    viewModel.SerialNumbers.Add(new SerialNumber());

            }
        }
        catch {

        }
        //viewModel.Product.Id = (args.NewTextValue);
    }
    public void AddItemClicked (object sender, EventArgs args){
        viewModel.Stocks.Add(new Stock { StoreId = App.currentStore.StoreId });
    }
}

}
```

**AddStocksPage XAML code: I have tried two methods, one is commented out **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="InventoryManager.Views.AddStocksPage"
            xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:InventoryManager.ViewModels">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Add" Clicked="AddItemClicked" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewmodels:AddStocksViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<ContentPage.Content>

  <StackLayout>

      <ListView x:Name="stockListView" IsGroupingEnabled="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Stocks}" >
          <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Spacing="3" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                     <Entry Text="{Binding ProductId}"  Placeholder="Product Id" TextChanged="OnProductIdChanged"  x:Name="productIdEntry" />
                     <Entry Text="{Binding StoreId}"  Placeholder="Store Id" IsEnabled="False"/>
                     <Entry Text="{Binding  Source={x:Reference quantityStepper}, Path=Value, StringFormat='{0}'}" Placeholder="Quantity" TextChanged="OnQuantityChanged" />
                     <Stepper x:Name="quantityStepper"   Maximum="360" Increment="1"  HorizontalOptions="Center" Value="{Binding Quantity}" />
                     </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell>
               </DataTemplate>

              </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
           <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout>
                              <Entry Text="{Binding SerialNumber.SerialNumberValue}" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

      </ListView>

      </StackLayout>
        <!--<StackLayout>

    <ListView x:Name="stockListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Stocks}" IsGroupingEnabled="True"  >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                 <ViewCell.View>
                     <StackLayout Orientation= "Vertical" Spacing="3">
                    <StackLayout Spacing="3" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                     <Entry Text="{Binding ProductId}"  Placeholder="Product Id" TextChanged="OnProductIdChanged"  x:Name="productIdEntry" />
                     <Entry Text="{Binding StoreId}"  Placeholder="Store Id" IsEnabled="False"/>
                     <Entry Text="{Binding  Source={x:Reference quantityStepper}, Path=Value, StringFormat='{0}'}" Placeholder="Quantity" TextChanged="OnQuantityChanged" />
                     <Stepper x:Name="quantityStepper"   Maximum="360" Increment="1"  HorizontalOptions="Center" Value="{Binding Quantity}" />
                     </StackLayout>
                     <ListView x:Name="serialListView" ItemsSource="{Binding SerialNumbers}"   IsVisible="true" >
                         IsVisible="{ Binding IsProductAPhone}"
                     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                         <DataTemplate>
                              <TextCell Text="{Binding SerialNumber.SerialNumberValue}" />
                         </DataTemplate>
                     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                  </ListView>

                    </StackLayout> 
            </ViewCell.View>
          </ViewCell>


              </DataTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
    </StackLayout>-->



</ContentPage.Content>
```

Please let me know of any tips/advice. Any sample code as to how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: have you read the docs on Grouped ListView?  They're pretty thorough.  However, they depend on the grouping to be setup a certain way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Jason Mentioned have a read threw the Documents I'll Provide you with some Information I found on a quick Google Search.

I wouldn't not recommend Nestled Listviews its just bad practice. My honest Opinion Would be to stop and rethink this.

I would rather say Have a look at Tableview's or again as Jason mentioned Grouped Listviews.With Tableviews You can Add your conditional logic when the page loads And add to the Tableview From the code behind this way you'll have more control over what's going in and what's not, Especially as you mentioned, You want to Separate Logic For Stock/Accessories.

A Topic on Nested Listviews:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/100280/nested-listview-in-xamarin-forms-listview-inside-another-listview

Listview Grouping:
https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-listview-grouping/

Sample for Grouping:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-listview-grouping/

---

Update Below

Do u have any kind of button on the rows? They would be your most reliable way of doing this, At-least in my Opinion. So What you do is you set the BindingContex of the button to the "Key" or w.e Identifier you have, And then get the context of the item

Threw the event args

```cs
 int check;

            var btn = (YourButton)sender;

            var item = btn.BindingContext; //You can find other Properties of the said Item aswell

            check = Convert.ToInt32(item);
```

Here's How id do it on the Item selection instead of the button hope it helps

```cs
 var obj = (YourCollection)e.SelectedItem;
            var ide = Convert.ToInt32(obj.PId); //Get the Item's Id or w.e els youd like to grab from the collection


//Below is a little Example of how i'm getting the current indexed items ID To use for later
            foreach (var item in z)
            {
                if (ide == item.PId)
                {
                    currentID = item.PId;


                }
            }
```

Comment: Appreciate your reply! I managed to do the grouping by inheriting the group class from ObservableCollection. Now, I am trying to use the stepper value in order to add rows to the stepper's parent item, if its a Serial item. Any tips as to how to get the index of the item in the upper observable collection?

Comment: It is Updated let me know if you need me to explain anything?

Comment: @Mike if the answer helped you please dont forget to mark it as correct, so if other people see this they know it worked.

Comment: Apologies, your response was great help! Done